# Remove A node from firebase in android

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to remove a node from firebase when a button is pushed.

I get the specific user id of the node i want to remove but nothing seems to happen. The code i am using is below. I am passing in the ID of the node i want to delete here with userIdKey, is that not correct??

```
   databaseEmpID.child("users").child(userIdKey).removeValue();
```

[image: Database IMage of node to be removed]

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Try with**

```
databaseEmpID.child("users").child(userIdKey).setValue(null);
```

ideally first please debug and check if `databaseEmpID.child("users").child(userIdKey)` refers to the node you want to delete.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, it was showing the right id so i wasnt sure where i was going wrong. I have resloved it now with   databaseEmpID.child(userIdKey).removeValue();

Comment: Okay. Thank for notifying, but I think rather than removing with removeValue() go for setValue(null) as best practice.

Comment: refer to this : https://medium.com/a-practical-guide-to-firebase-on-android/updating-and-deleting-from-your-firebase-database-bc8d39573829

Comment: Can you please explain why using setValue(null) instead of removeValue() is best practice?

Answer (score 0):

try to use OnFailure or onComplete Listeners and check exception.!

```
 dbNode.child("users").child(userIdKey)

dbNode.removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Unable to delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```